# How to run supported games on Steam with Proton

Tags: steam

Human Fall Flat works flawlessly on Windows, but I am having problem with Linux. I installed this game on Ubuntu 19.04 and it works fine, except it's an older verison and multiplayer doesn't work on there. I just found out about Proton on steam and so I installed it and reinstalled HFF, however, it still installs the old version that doesn't allow me to play multiplayer, help!

(Only the game's older version can port to Linux without Proton)

Answer (score 2):

In Steam settings in the category "Steam Play" check "Enable Steam Play for all other titles".

Then right-click on the game in question, open "Properties", and on the bottom of the "General" tab, check "Force the use of a specific Steam Play compatibility tool".

That will tell Steam to run the game via Proton even if there is a native Linux version available.

Comment: Thanks for this! Do I need to re-install the game somehow after enabling this option?

Comment: No - Steam should download the required files automatically, just like if it would download an update.